# Unexpected token '?' when using discord-player

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

im pretty new to coding and i wanted to make a music bot. Discord-player looked like a really good option because the documentation is very basic and good for beginners so after scripting my bot i keep getting this error when running my script:

```
/Users/NAME/node_modules/discord-player/src/Player.js:608
    }, this.options.leaveOnEmptyCooldown ?? 0)
                                          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1053:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jamiedias1/node_modules/discord-player/index.js
```

Is this a problem with my code because it doesnt reference my code.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: It looks like that version of discord-player depends on Node 14.x.x: https://github.com/Androz2091/discord-player/issues/112

Answer (score 0):

That's a very specific pattern called Nullish Coalescing. What browser are you seeing the error on? It's not supported in anything internet explorer:

https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_nullish_coalescing